# Installing apps offline

Tags: 19.04, offline

I recently installed Ubuntu for the first time, but I'm having trouble installing apps, the internet connection here is quite slow. In my office I downloaded some apps from uptodown.com but when I try to install them there's a problem with the dependencies. I want to know how to download the apps with the dependencies from my windows computer and then install them offline in my Ubuntu system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 0):

> In my office I downloaded some apps from uptodown.com but when I try to install them there's a problem with the dependencies

That is a problem uptodown.com needs to fix for you: they should alert you about dependencies and offer to download those too. Or let you download the snap version (those include all dependencies).

> I want to know how to download the apps with the dependencies from my windows computer

See [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) for official supported software. From their list they include [gedit](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/gedit). The link will show you all the dependencies needed to install gedit (though that one is likely already installed).

For all 3rd party software (and most of those on that website are) you will need to visit their respective website and see what they list as a dependency.